# Regex to find WSDL files in HTML

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing a discover service that takes a URL and returns the HTML located at that page.

From that page, I need to "scrape" all the WSDL URL's.

So I need something like the following, but I am not sure how to specify the regex to pass into the pattern matching.

```
string wsdlPattern = //SOME REGEX THAT MATCHES WSDL http:{address}wsdl
Regex wsdlRegex = new Reges(wsdlPattern);
MatchCollection matches = wsdlRegex.Match(html);
```

Can somebody please help me figure how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`http://[^\s]*?.wsdl`

The regular text parts are obvious: it needs to start with `http://` and end with `.wsdl`.  `[^\s]` means "any non-whitespace character", and `*?` means "as few as possible" (this is necessary in case you have something like `http://www.blah.com/a.wsdl<br>http://www.blah.com/b.wsdl`.  Without the `?`, you'd match that whole thing as one string.)

This isn't perfect, but it should get you started.

If you want to play with regex, this is a great resource:
http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr

Answer (score 1):

I used below RE for validting WSDL urls, as you can see I had to check if they end with "*?wsdl*"

RE : `(http|https):\/\/[^\s]*?.\?wsdl`

Ignore Case : `(?i)(http|https):\/\/[^\s]*?.\?wsdl(?-i)`

( Test Case : `http://localhost/WebService1.asmx?wSDl` )

Answer (score 0):

wsdls can be uploaded using ftp and files as well therefore:

```
(http|https|ftp|file)://[^\s]*?.(wsdl|WSDL)
```

Hope this helps!